# edGet the value of element inside ng-repeat dynamically

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am generating 10 elements using ng-repeat.

Please help me to get the value of each span tag dynamically so that I can write conditions accordingly.

Below is my html code.

I tried

```
 $('span').attr('value');
```

```html
<span ng-repeat="n in [].constructor(7) track by $index" class="dot" value="{{$index+1}}">{{$index+1}}</span>
```

Comment: what syntax is this `{{$index+1}}` ?

Comment: and this `[].constructor(7)`?

Comment: this is to set the limit of ng-repeat and {{$index+1}} is to display the number

Comment: have you tried a custom directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(obj).attr('value'))` where `obj` is a DOMSpanElement. E.g. `var obj = $('span')[i]`

```js
function check(){
  $('span').each(
    function (i,obj){
      alert($(obj).attr('value'))
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app>
  
<span id="values" ng-repeat="n in [].constructor(7) track by $index" class="dot" value="{{$index+1}}">{{ $index+1 }}</span>
  
</div>

<div>
  <button onclick="check()">Check</button>
</div>
```